# How to write SQL query to sort sequential data

Tags: sql, self-join

Here is an example table:

| id | content | previous | next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Preheat an oven to 220 degrees C. | NULL | 2 |
| 2 | Peel potatoes. | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | Toss sliced potatoes with oil. | 4 | 6 |
| 4 | Cut potatoes into slices. | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | Season the slices. | 6 | NULL |
| 6 | Bake in the oven for 30 minutes. | 3 | 5 |

How to sort them in the correct order? I tried this:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.content,
    t2.content as next_step
FROM t_name t1
INNER JOIN t2
      ON t1.next_id = t2.id
```

The output still has the content in the same order, just added `next_step` column. I tried using `SELECT content FROM t_name ORDER BY previous_id`, still incorrect. How do I sort this table in sequential order?

To clarify what the output should be (see below). It can have an extra `id` column with the correct id number, but it is not required. The answer hint says using a self-join, but I am unable to get it done besides attempting a recursive cte.

| content |
| --- |
| Preheat an oven to 220 degrees C. |
| Peel potatoes. |
| Cut potatoes into slices. |
| Toss sliced potatoes with oil. |
| Bake in the oven for 30 minutes. |
| Season the slices. |

Comment: I recall having done something very similar with recursive CTEs. Maybe this'll help: https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-recursive-cte/

Comment: Could you give us an example of a fully sorted table? It'll help us determine how you want things to be sorted (IE copy/paste the original table down at the bottom and sort the rows by hand.)

Comment: I'm not understanding your question...

Comment: Yes, you need to use recursive cte to follow the chain of links and within this cte there will be self-join.

Comment: Okay. Thank y'all for the help. I will try the recursive cte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it with [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

```
select           "content"
from             t
start with       "previous" is null
connect by prior "next" = "id"
```

| content |
| --- |
| Preheat an oven to 220 degrees C. |
| Peel potatoes. |
| Cut potatoes into slices. |
| Toss sliced potatoes with oil. |
| Bake in the oven for 30 minutes. |
| Season the slices. |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fca9e1f7bf9fdcb8d3405ef7e6afeaba&hide=3)

Comment: Good use of `connect by prior`! I had completely forgotten that Oracle had a way of avoiding recursive CTE's in restricted cases.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive cte in MySQL gives the correct result:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
           SELECT 
             id, 
             content, 
             next_id
           FROM example_t
           WHERE previous_id IS NULL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 
              e.id, 
              e.content, 
              e.next_id
           FROM example_t e
           INNER JOIN cte c
           on e.id=c.next_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```